# How to force remove text after footer in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this text, once I include some vuejs extension. I need the extension badly but it seem that it cause some text to display on my footer.

**Is there any hack to remove it**?.[image]

Please check immediately after my footer, there some text there.I don't have editing tool to edit the image.

Please help

Comment: Which vue js extention you used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use JavaScript to remove that div element.

```
let footer = document.getElementsByClassName("footer");
footer.remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use some CSS to simply hide it. It might not be ideal, but could work just fine depending on your situation.

```
.footer{
    display:none;
{
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be ```display: none !important``` as the footer already has styling from the package?